# How to check whether a service is running in linux?

Tags: linux, services

I run a script manually like/usr/lib/openoffice.org/program/soffice and when I run

```
:ps -ef|grep openoffice
```

I get the following,

root  700     1  0 10:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/openoffice.org/program/soffice -calc

My question is how to check whether  this script is running or not (It can be checked every 10 minutes) and how to make it as a service. (I don't have root access to put this in rc.local file or somewhere else).

Comment: This should be moved to superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pidof` to get pid of process

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while true
do
 pidof openoffice 1>/dev/null
 if [ $? -eq "1" ];then
  /usr/lib/openoffice.org/program/soffice &
 fi
 sleep 600
done
```